# Update Blues: install.packages("XXX")

Tags: r

So I recently (1 hour ago) updated to a 64-bit version of R and tried installing some of my trusty packages in the fresh install (Windows seperates 64/32 bit programs now in two program folders).

Is there a work around for this?

```
Warning message:
In getDependencies(pkgs, dependencies, available, lib) : package ‘RMySQL’ is not available
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it sorted. Download and install manually:

```
install.packages("C:\\Path\\to\\file\\windows_binary.zip",repos=NULL)
```

Happy Friday!